# Can not see indicators nor are the slides moving in Bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-carousel

I am making a website using bootstrap, and it seems the carousel is not working, I copied the code directly from their page and it still won't work.

I don't see the indicators, nor do I see it moving (I have 3 slides of content).
This is all I see:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>realatte task</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid carousel-section-1">
    <div id="carouselIndicators" class="carousel slide mt-4" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block" src="testimonial.png" alt="First slide">
          <p>"Im wondering why never contacted these guys sooner! Seriously, they all have commendable talent in their respective field and knocked my concept out of the ballpark. Thanks for an amazing experience!"</p>
          <p class="mt-3">-Segero, NoranicMeds</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block" src="testimonial.png" alt="Second slide">
          <p>"Im wondering why never contacted these guys sooner! Seriously, they all have commendable talent in their respective field and knocked my concept out of the ballpark. Thanks for an amazing experience!"</p>
          <p class="mt-3">-Segero, NoranicMeds</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block" src="testimonial.png" alt="Third slide">
          <p>"Im wondering why never contacted these guys sooner! Seriously, they all have commendable talent in their respective field and knocked my concept out of the ballpark. Thanks for an amazing experience!"</p>
          <p class="mt-3">-Segero, NoranicMeds</p>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add these bootstrap links on the header**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And the data-target is 'data-target="#carouselIndicators". Same target you have to use on the **Prev** & **Next** Buttons

```
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>realatte task</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- CSS only -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
        <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid carousel-section-1">
            <div id="carouselIndicators" class="carousel slide mt-4" data-ride="carousel">
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              </ol>
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <img class="d-block" src="https://www.ispydesign.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/bokeh-cover-bg.jpg" alt="First slide">
                  <p>"Im wondering why never contacted these guys sooner! Seriously, they all have commendable talent in their respective field and knocked my concept out of the ballpark. Thanks for an amazing experience!"</p>
                  <p class="mt-3">-Segero, NoranicMeds</p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block" src="https://www.ispydesign.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/bokeh-cover-bg.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                  <p>"Im wondering why never contacted these guys sooner! Seriously, they all have commendable talent in their respective field and knocked my concept out of the ballpark. Thanks for an amazing experience!"</p>
                  <p class="mt-3">-Segero, NoranicMeds</p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block" src="https://www.ispydesign.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/bokeh-cover-bg.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                  <p>"Im wondering why never contacted these guys sooner! Seriously, they all have commendable talent in their respective field and knocked my concept out of the ballpark. Thanks for an amazing experience!"</p>
                  <p class="mt-3">-Segero, NoranicMeds</p>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try using this**

```css
.carousel .carousel-indicators {
    margin-bottom: -1rem;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>realatte task</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- CSS only -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-indicators">
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
                <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
                  <img class="d-block" src="testimonial.png" alt="First slide">
                    <p>"Im wondering why never contacted these guys sooner! Seriously, they all have commendable talent in their respective field and knocked my concept out of the ballpark. Thanks for an amazing experience!"</p>
                    <p class="mt-3">-Segero, NoranicMeds</p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
                  <img class="d-block" src="testimonial.png" alt="Second slide">
                    <p>"Im wondering why never contacted these guys sooner! Seriously, they all have commendable talent in their respective field and knocked my concept out of the ballpark. Thanks for an amazing experience!"</p>
                    <p class="mt-3">-Segero, NoranicMeds</p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block" src="testimonial.png" alt="Second slide">
                    <p>"Im wondering why never contacted these guys sooner! Seriously, they all have commendable talent in their respective field and knocked my concept out of the ballpark. Thanks for an amazing experience!"</p>
                    <p class="mt-3">-Segero, NoranicMeds</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
              </button>
              <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
              </button>
            </div>
    </div>
        
        <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so i used your code and i got the next and prev buttons but the indicators did not appear!

Comment: Now check, the indicators were above the text